# unexpected t-variable, cant see what is causing it

Tags: php

I am getting an unexpected T_variable on line 445 but I can't see where the problem is, can anyone see where the problem is which is causing this error?

```
//start:procedure
$img_result = '';
if(empty($arrImageFile[$key])){
  $img_result = '&nbsp;';
}else{
  $img_$result .=  '<ul class="qandaul"><li>'; //line 445
   if(is_array( $arrImageFile[$key] )){
    foreach($arrImageFile[$key] as $filename){
     $img_$result.= CreateLink($filename, "image");
    }
   }else{
    $img_$result.= CreateLink($arrImageFile[$key], "image");
   }
   $img_result.= '</li></ul>';
}
//end:procedure

echo '<td width="11%" class="imagetd">'.$img_result.'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: There's an extra `$` in `$img_$result` in three different places.

Comment: @lafor Thanks, I was looking hard at brackets, semi colons and $ at start of varialbes that I did not see $ inbetween variables. Thanks. Put in answer if you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$img_$result` should be: `$img_result` and that should be fixed on line 448 and 451 aswell.
Remember that `T_VARIABLE` usually refers to the `$` variable symbol.
If you want to use the [variable of variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) feature you should use `$$img_result` or `${$img_result}` for better understanding.